# Efficient way to read, transform and output results in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Have 150 txt.gz files about 1.3 GB each. All files have same column structure, 4 columns. Only want to keep Col1 and remove dups from Col1 while keeping track of what files those values came from. Goal is to get all unique values from Col1 from all files and the file name into one csv file.  Though 150 files * 1.3gb have a lot of data, after removing dups of col1 and only using col1, size of results should only be around 200,000 rows 2 cols.
Csv results would be:
| value1| filename|
| value2| filename|

Current I have the below. But it's slow. I tried outputting to parquet but that's even slower therefore I ended up using pandas which is the fastest it seems for outputting results. I'm using pyspark and on a spark platform setup correctly. What would be an efficient way to read, process and output these txt.gz files?

```
schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("Col1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Col2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Col3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Col4", StringType(), True)
])

result_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(0, 150):
    file = f'{x}.txt.gz'
    sprk_df= spark.read.format('csv').load(file, schema=schema, header=False, quote="'")
    
    sprk_df= sprk_df.select(spark_df['Col1']).distinct()
    
    df = sprk_df.toPandas()
    df['FileName'] = file
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, df])


result_df.to_csv("results")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv` data source to read and save a dataframe.

### Read

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true', quote='"',
                                                           delimiter=',').load('./20210507.csv')
```

### Write

```
targetDf.repartition(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save(
    "20210507modified")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all files at the same time use folder path instead of file. no need for a for loop . Beats the purpose of using spark using for loop. It can read .gzip files directly as well.

Below is just the psuedo code

```
sprk_df= spark.read.format('csv').load(folderpath, schema=schema, header=False, quote="'")
sprk_df= sprk_df.select(spark_df['Col1']).distinct()
sprk_df.write.format(csv)
```